# Running UPDATE SQL from ADF Pipeline returns 'Failed to execute the query command during read operation.' error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that has several different stages, and one of the things I want to do is update a table on Snowflake at certain points to track where the pipeline has got up to.

When I try to run this simple pipeline I get the following error:

[image]

What the process is doing, is finding some header data from a file, storing it in a variable, and then trying to update our starting table with that header value in a specific header column:

[image]

The script that is failing is a simple update:

```
@concat('update schema.loadcontrol
set fileheader = ',string(variables('RawHeader')),
'where loadnumber = ',variables('LoadNumber'))
```

If I remove the RawHeader variable and have it be a set value such as 12345, it works fine, even with the LoadNumber being a variable too.

Does anyone know why it might not like the RawHeader variable, which is just a standard 25 character string?

The table it is inserting into on Snowflake is a varchar(50) so theres plenty of space for it.

Comment: can you go to snowflake monitor and check the actual error and add it here?

Comment: If fileheader is a varchar(50) then you might need to wrap the variable value with single quotes.  What did it look like when you set the constant value 12345 - was it wrapped with quotes?

Comment: @PratikLad I cant see any record of the query on Snowflake so its like it didn't managed to get there? I see on ADF its trying to run this when I look at the 'Input' section of the step:
           "type": "NonQuery",
            "text": "update schema.LOADCONTROL\nset fileheader = current_datetime\nwhere loadnumber =39"

loadnumber = 39 matches my variable, current_datetime is the default value I put in to the variable

Comment: @ScottMildenberger It wasn't no, when viewing the table directly after using 12345 it appeared exactly as 12345

Comment: Looks to me  like the current_datetime is where your problem is.  Try setting your RawHeader variable to 12345 and see if that works.  That would help isolate the problem because if that works then it is the current_datetime that isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't know if this is going to lead to an answer but certainly hope so. A few things stand out to me:

- it seems quite logical that you can't 'update' (or so to spreak: write) during a "read operation" - that literally is what it says and that sound kinda funny. But as you say it works with just inputting a number there, you might as well skip this remark.
- next to that, it seems like the formatting for the sql command string your might be a bit off. That could explain why integers work and literals fail. Could it be you're missing some quotes there to feed a literal value on the spot you seem to want it?

Love to know if it helped!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont know why its a read operation when the script is set to Non-Query which is defined as:
Database statements that perform catalog operations (for example, querying the structure of a database or creating database objects such as tables), or change the data in a database by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.

Which my script would hopefully fall in to.

Comment: Hopefully indeed, because I have had errors come up like these which were because of DDL rights I needed. That's not the case here as then the integers wouldn't have come through. Anyways, speaking of integers, did you have time to test my second remark, formatting your SQL command with apostrophes and commas?

Comment: Thanks I think that did it, because the variables were strings that needed to be enclosed in ' and ' is used to mark in the code, I had to double/triple up apostrophes in places for it to understand which part was the closure of the string and which part was an actual apostrophe in the string itself!

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear you figured it out and thanks for letting us know!